# Write HTML file using Java

Tags: java, html

I want my Java application to write HTML code in a file. Right now, I am hard coding HTML tags using java.io.BufferedWriter class. For Example:

```
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));
bw.write("<html><head><title>New Page</title></head><body><p>This is Body</p></body></html>");
bw.close();
```

Is there any easier way to do this, as I have to create tables and it is becoming very inconvenient?

Answer (score 51):

If you want to do that yourself, without using any external library, a clean way would be to create a `template.html` file with all the static content, like for example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>$title</title>
</head>
<body>$body
</body>
</html>
```

Put a tag like `$tag` for any dynamic content and then do something like this:

```
File htmlTemplateFile = new File("path/template.html");
String htmlString = FileUtils.readFileToString(htmlTemplateFile);
String title = "New Page";
String body = "This is Body";
htmlString = htmlString.replace("$title", title);
htmlString = htmlString.replace("$body", body);
File newHtmlFile = new File("path/new.html");
FileUtils.writeStringToFile(newHtmlFile, htmlString);
```

Note: I used [org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io///apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html) for simplicity.

Comment: For Java8, pass extra Charset.forName("UTF-8") because readFileToString without charset is deprecated.

Comment: It is also possible to use MessageFormat for substitutions: `String template = FileUtils.readFileToString(htmlTemplateFile);
    String title = "New Page";
    String body = "This is Body";
    String htmlString = MessageFormat.format(template, title, body);`
And `template` should then contain `{0}` for `title` and `{1}` for `body`.

Answer (score 13):

A few months ago I had the same problem and every library I found provides too much functionality and complexity for my final goal. So I end up developing my own library - *HtmlFlow* - that provides a very simple and intuitive API that allows me to write HTML in a fluent style. Check it here: https://github.com/fmcarvalho/HtmlFlow (it also supports *dynamic binding* to HTML elements)

Here is an example of binding the properties of a `Task` object into HTML elements. Consider a `Task` Java class with three properties: `Title`, `Description` and a `Priority` and then we can produce an HTML document for a `Task` object in the following way:

```
import htmlflow.HtmlView;

import model.Priority;
import model.Task;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintStream;

public class App {

    private static HtmlView<Task> taskDetailsView(){
        HtmlView<Task> taskView = new HtmlView<>();
        taskView
                .head()
                .title("Task Details")
                .linkCss("https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css");
        taskView
                .body().classAttr("container")
                .heading(1, "Task Details")
                .hr()
                .div()
                .text("Title: ").text(Task::getTitle)
                .br()
                .text("Description: ").text(Task::getDescription)
                .br()
                .text("Priority: ").text(Task::getPriority);
        return taskView;
    }

    public static void main(String [] args) throws IOException{
        HtmlView<Task> taskView = taskDetailsView();
        Task task =  new Task("Special dinner", "Have dinner with someone!", Priority.Normal);

        try(PrintStream out = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("Task.html"))){
            taskView.setPrintStream(out).write(task);
            Desktop.getDesktop().browse(URI.create("Task.html"));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A nice idea, and a nice tool, but unfortunately the license is not as nice so to encourage really broad use... ;)

Comment: @s-n-ushakov Sorry, I am not an expert about license agreements. What's the problem with GPL v3.0?

Comment: The problem with GPL is that it is too restrictive. It requires you to disclose all your project under GPL too, if you use just any piece of GPL-licensed code. This may be no problem for hobby or university programming, but it may be quite a problem for business-related programming. So to make your library more business-friendly, I might suggest to change the license at least to LGPL, which does not require you to opensource all your project, but only requires to disclose your improvements to the library. Other licenses, maybe slightly more business friendly, are BSD, MIT, Apache, Eclipse...

Comment: @s-n-ushakov I will change the license to MIT. Thanks for your advice.

Comment: Cool, nice to know that :)

Comment: @s-n-ushakov DONE. Just release it version 1.1. with MIT license and a couple of minor fixes.

Answer (score 8):

You can use [jsoup](https://jsoup.org/) or [wffweb](https://webfirmframework.github.io/) (HTML5) based.

Sample code for jsoup:-

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse("<html></html>");
doc.body().addClass("body-styles-cls");
doc.body().appendElement("div");
System.out.println(doc.toString());
```

prints

```
<html>
 <head></head>
 <body class=" body-styles-cls">
  <div></div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Sample code for wffweb:-

```
Html html = new Html(null) {{
    new Head(this);
    new Body(this,
        new ClassAttribute("body-styles-cls"));
}};

Body body = TagRepository.findOneTagAssignableToTag(Body.class, html);
body.appendChild(new Div(null));

System.out.println(html.toHtmlString());
//directly writes to file
html.toOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("/home/user/filepath/filename.html"), "UTF-8");
```

prints (in minified format):-

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body class="body-styles-cls">
    <div></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 7):

[Velocity](http://velocity.apache.org/) is a good candidate for writing this kind of stuff.
It allows you to keep your html and data-generation code as separated as possible.

Answer (score 7):

I would highly recommend you use a very simple templating language such as [Freemarker](http://freemarker.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 4):

It really depends on the type of HTML file you're creating.

For such tasks, I use to create an object, serialize it to XML, then transform it with XSL. The pros of this approach are:

- The strict separation between source code and HTML template,
- The possibility to edit HTML without having to recompile the application,
- The ability to serve different HTML in different cases based on the same XML, or even serve XML directly when needed (for a further deserialization for example),
- The shorter amount of code to write.

The cons are:

- You must know XSLT and know how to implement it in Java.
- You must write XSLT (and it's torture for many developers).
- When transforming XML to HTML with XSLT, some parts may be tricky. Few examples: `<textarea/>` tags (which make the page unusable), XML declaration (which can cause problems with IE), whitespace (with `<pre></pre>` tags etc.), HTML entities (`&nbsp;`), etc.
- The performance will be reduced, since serialization to XML wastes lots of CPU resources and XSL transformation is very costly too.

Now, if your HTML is very short or very repetitive or if the HTML has a volatile structure which changes dynamically, this approach must not be taken in account. On the other hand, if you serve HTML files which have all a similar structure and you want to reduce the amount of Java code and use templates, this approach may work.

Answer (score 4):

I had also problems in finding something simple to satisfy my needs so I decided to write my own library (with MIT license).
It's mainly based on composite and builder pattern.

A basic declarative example is:

```
import static com.github.manliogit.javatags.lang.HtmlHelper.*;

html5(attr("lang -> en"),
  head(
    meta(attr("http-equiv -> Content-Type", "content -> text/html; charset=UTF-8")),
    title("title"),
    link(attr("href -> xxx.css", "rel -> stylesheet"))
  )
).render();
```

A fluent example is:

```
ul()
  .add(li("item 1"))
  .add(li("item 2"))
  .add(li("item 3"))
```

You can check more examples [here](https://github.com/manlioGit/javatags)

I also created an [on line converter](https://javatagsconverter.fly.dev) to transform *every* html snippet (from complex bootstrap template to simple single snippet) on the fly (i.e. html -> javatags)

Comment: Works will, very elegant!

Comment: `attr("href -> xxx.css",...` gives the impression, that the library incurs parsing overhead for writing. Why not `attrs(attr("href", "xxx.css"), ...)`?

Answer (score 2):

Templates and other methods based on preliminary creation of the document in memory are likely to impose certain limits on resulting document size.

Meanwhile a very straightforward and reliable write-on-the-fly approach to creation of plain HTML exists, based on a SAX handler and default XSLT transformer, the latter having intrinsic capability of HTML output:

```
String encoding = "UTF-8";
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("myfile.html");
OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(fos, encoding);
StreamResult streamResult = new StreamResult(writer);

SAXTransformerFactory saxFactory =
    (SAXTransformerFactory) TransformerFactory.newInstance();
TransformerHandler tHandler = saxFactory.newTransformerHandler();
tHandler.setResult(streamResult);

Transformer transformer = tHandler.getTransformer();
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.METHOD, "html");
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, encoding);
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");

writer.write("<!DOCTYPE html>\n");
writer.flush();
tHandler.startDocument();
    tHandler.startElement("", "", "html", new AttributesImpl());
        tHandler.startElement("", "", "head", new AttributesImpl());
            tHandler.startElement("", "", "title", new AttributesImpl());
                tHandler.characters("Hello".toCharArray(), 0, 5);
            tHandler.endElement("", "", "title");
        tHandler.endElement("", "", "head");
        tHandler.startElement("", "", "body", new AttributesImpl());
            tHandler.startElement("", "", "p", new AttributesImpl());
                tHandler.characters("5 > 3".toCharArray(), 0, 5); // note '>' character
            tHandler.endElement("", "", "p");
        tHandler.endElement("", "", "body");
    tHandler.endElement("", "", "html");
tHandler.endDocument();
writer.close();
```

Note that XSLT transformer will release you from the burden of escaping special characters like `>`, as it takes necessary care of it by itself.

And it is easy to wrap SAX methods like `startElement()` and `characters()` to something more convenient to one's taste...

Comment: Nice idea using only standard tools. Unfortunately, it is tedious to write `tHandler.startElement("", "", "p", new AttributesImpl())` - even worse, if one wants to set set a CSS class on an element...

Comment: @haui Well, that was just an idea. It is possible to define some shorthand wrappers around these standard calls to save some typing or copypasting... :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing to use Groovy, the MarkupBuilder is very convenient for this sort of thing, but I don't know that Java has anything like it.

http://groovy.codehaus.org/Creating+XML+using+Groovy's+MarkupBuilder

Answer (score 0):

if it is becoming repetitive work ; i think you shud do code reuse ! why dont you simply write functions that "write" small building blocks of HTML. get the idea? see Eg. you can have a function to which you could pass a string and it would automatically put that into a paragraph tag and present it. Of course you would also need to write some kind of a basic parser to do this (how would the function know where to attach the paragraph!). i dont think you are  a beginner .. so i am not elaborating ... do tell me if you do not understand..

Answer (score 0):

Try the `ujo-web` library, which supports building `HTML` pages using the `Element` class. Here is a sample use case based on a Java servlet:

```java
@WebServlet("/form-servlet")
public class FormServlet extends HttpServlet {
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws IOException {

        try (HtmlElement html = HtmlElement.niceOf(response, "/style.css")) {
            try (Element body = html.addBody()) {
                body.addHeading("Simple form");
                try (Element form = body.addForm("form-inline")) {
                    form.addLabel("control-label").addText("Note:");
                    form.addInput("form-control", "col-lg-1")
                            .setNameValue(NOTE, NOTE.of(request));
                    form.addSubmitButton("btn", "btn-primary")
                            .addText("Submit");
                }
            }
        }
    }

    enum Attrib implements HttpParameter {
        NOTE;
        @Override public String toString() {
            return name().toLowerCase();
        }
    }
}
```

The servlet generates the next HTML code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
        <title>Demo</title>
        <link href="/css/regexp.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Simple form</h1>
        <form class="form-inline">
            <label class="control-label">Note:</label>
            <input class="form-control col-lg-1" name="note" value=""/>
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

See more information here: https://ujorm.org/www/web/