# How to implement Java Variables in a HTML file before sending it?

Tags: java

What I'm doing here is to get a html file, read it, write it and send it to me.

Is there any way to write it THEN replace some parts with Java variables to implement for example the Year, Name... ?

```
 private static String readFile(String path) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader br= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                new FileInputStream(path), "UTF8"));
        StringBuilder content=new StringBuilder();
        String s="";
        while((s=br.readLine())!=null)
            {
            content.append(s);
            }
        return content.toString();
    }
```

Comment: in your while loop, what is stopping you from altering s?

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5936003/write-html-file-using-java/15368262